# Consuming Rest Ionic3

Tags: angular, rest, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am new to the web and Ionic3 development and I have a problem, I followed a tutorial to consume a rest API, I was able to bring the list with the users, however I am wanting to bring a specific user and show it on screen if I change the URL for the user it shows me this error

```
TabCepPage.html:10 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object
'[object Object]' of type 'Leanne Graham'. NgFor only supports binding 
to  Iterables such as Arrays.
```

my app is like this:

provider: rest.ts

```
apiUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  console.log('Hello RestServiceProvider Provider');
}

getUsers() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.get(this.apiUrl+'/users/1').subscribe(data => {
      resolve(data);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  });
}
```

page .ts:

```
users: any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public restProvider: RestProvider) {
  this.getUsers();
}

getUsers() {
  this.restProvider.getUsers()
  .then(data => {
    this.users = data;
    console.log(this.users);
  });
}
```

and so on HTML display:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let user of users">
  <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
  <p>{{user.email}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

Can u help me?

Comment: what is output of `console.log(this.users);`

Comment: {id: 1, name: "Leanne Graham", username: "Bret", email: "Sincere@april.biz", address: {…}, …}
address
:
{street: "Kulas Light", suite: "Apt. 556", city: "Gwenborough", zipcode: "92998-3874", geo: {…}}
company
:
{name: "Romaguera-Crona", catchPhrase: "Multi-layered client-server neural-net", bs: "harness real-time e-markets"}
email
:
"Sincere@april.biz"
id
:
1
name
:
"Leanne Graham"
phone
:
"1-770-736-8031 x56442"
username
:
"Bret"
website
:
"hildegard.org"
__proto__
:
Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to get an specific user on your code, this.users ends up being an object instead of an array which is what your template is trying to for loop. You just need to update the template to display the object instead of trying to for loop it.

```
example:
<ion-item *ngIf="users">
  <h2>{{users.name}}</h2>
  <p>{{users.email}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

you what to see that array  you can use 
 console.log(JSON.stringify(variable name));